# How to change property values at runtime in SpringBoot without restarting/redeploying the app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

This is an extension to this question: [How change property values at runtime in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38761781/how-change-property-values-at-runtime-in-spring)

I don't want to restart my app if I change some properties in a property file, how can I achieve this.

**Example:**

Let's say I have 2 profiles: dev, and prod

***application-dev.properties***

```
shouldSendFailureEmail = false
```

***application-prod.properties***

```
shouldSendFailureEmail = true
```

For debugging purpose I want to enable email to be sent in dev environment as well, even if I change the property file the changes are not getting reflected unless I restart the app.

Running Springboot application using this command :

```
 java 
      -Dspring.config.location=/ngs/app/seat/config/ 
      -Dspring.config.name=neerajportal -Dspring.profiles.active=qa 
      -Djava.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism=40 
      -jar /ngs/app/java-apps/NeerajPortal.war
```

Comment: Did you try using spring-cloud-config? it provides a `refresh` endpoint

Comment: @noiaverbale Correct it's duplicate thanks for pointing in the right direction. _sukhpal Spring Cloud Config server may be overkill for some use cases.